# How to I get C# FileContentResult response in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, http, client-server

I have a C# Web API which returns `FileContentResult`. Here is my code

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("Download")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<DownloadResponse>> DownloadFiles(int fileDocumentId)
    {
            var file = ... ; // code removed for brevity
            return File(file.FileData , file.FileType, file.FileName);
    }

public class DownloadResponse
{
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileData { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

and my front-end Javascript, I managed to call the web API and able to get the response.

```
function download(id) {
    fetch(`https://localhost:xxx/api/file/download?fileDocumentId=11`)
        .then(response => {
            return response
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);                
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error)
        });
}
```

When I `console.log(result);`, there are a lot of properties. Which property has the response data so that I can see the `FileData` and `FileName` data?

[image]

Comment: You have to call a method. `const response = await fetch(...); const data = await response.blob();`

Comment: As Aluan Haddad said, to access the content of the file you'll need to use the blob method on the response. To get the file name you'll need to look at the content-disposition response header.